# If my user sessions lasts 30 minutes, what is the correct amount of time that my Oauth2 access token should last?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I wanted to clarify something about OAuth2.  Let’s say I have a web based application and a resource, /dashboard, that is user specific and that I wish to protect via OAuth2.  Further assume my user session lasts 30 minutes.  Typically I’ve seen validity values for access tokens of 30 seconds.  So, if my user logs in, gets an access token, and then fails to access /dashboard within 30 seconds, do they then have to make two requests to the browser — one to get the access token and a second, using that access token to get the /dashboard resource?  That seems massively inconvenient.  Should I just make my access token length the same as my session length to avoid such an inconvenience?

I’m using Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE, Spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE, and oauth2 2.0.5.RELEASE if that’s of any value.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access token validity period is more of a convenience than a standard. Twitter for example never revokes tokens unless explicitly done so by the user. So if your session is supposed to be valid for 30 minutes, you can set the access token validity to 30 minutes.

Comment: Sounds good, but assuming the user continues active in the session beyond 30 minutes, when that initial 30 minutes is up, they will have to request a new access token is that correct?

Comment: Ok, but how is this better than normal Spring security?  It seems like more of a hassle for the end-user without really gaining you anything.